# Stopping media player before playing next audio

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am having a listview in my app. Each listview item has button which will play an audio from a url received from web service. But my problem is that if I click play button from the next item then both start playing together. I am having problem in this. I want only one to play at a time. Right now I am creating new Media player object everytime button is clicked, but I also tried creating a single global object but in this case it only plays first time and not after it. What is the possible solution of it.

```
finalHolder.iv_sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                            mp.setDataSource(birdsUrlList.get(position).getUrl_audio());
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    mp.start();
                                }
                            });
                            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    mp.release();
                                }
                            });
                            //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(birdsUrlList.get(position).getUrl_video())));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `mp` variable global and remove this:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();
    }
});
```

because if you take a look at this reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram it says:

> Once the MediaPlayer object is in the End state, it can no longer be
>   used and there is no way to bring it back to any other state.

And when you call `mp.release();` the media player WILL go to that state.

Then make your onClickListener look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }

        mp.setDataSource(birdsUrlList.get(position).getUrl_audio());
        //... and so on

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
        });
```

The trick there is to make it back to Idle state so you can set the new data source and start playing again. It's all about the states...

Comment: I tried making mp global and I have already mentioned that in my question, however I will try removvng on completion

Comment: no this didn't work, I can't play again if I make it global

Comment: Well have you debugged that it even goes to that mp.start(); line ever again??

Comment: after first time it starts throwing illegal state exception

Comment: Stop and reset thing worked. I was always calling release instead.Thanks